# SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) is ALWAYS false in _LoginPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a web application with Identity in order to manage authentication.

But I have this issue:
in _LoginPartial.cshtml `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` is always false (even if the user is right/login is successfull):

```
@inject SignInManager<myAppUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<myAppUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) 
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

my Program.cs is:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContextConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<myAppContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<myAppIdentityContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
})
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme)
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)

    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddMvc();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<myAppUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    // Password settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;
    // Lockout settings.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    // User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
 .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
 .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<myAppUser>>()
 .AddDefaultUI()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<myAppIdentityContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseMemberCasing();  //for DexExtreme
    });


//mail sender
builder.Services.Configure<SmtpSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SmtpSettings)));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MailService>();

#region API

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml"));
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = string.Format("JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter '{0}' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"{0} 1safsfsdfdfd\"", "Bearer")
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[]{}
                    }
                });
    options.SchemaFilter<SwaggerEnumHelper>(); 
    options.DocumentFilter<SwaggerDocumentFilterHelper>();
});

#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "myapplication.WebAPI v1"));
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

//app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

myAppUser.cs is:

```
[Table("AspNetUsers", Schema = "dbo")]
public class myAppUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I've tried so maaany solutions before writing this question, but nothing goes right.

I want `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` return true after a successfull login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved in this way. My Program.cs became like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContextConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<myAppContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<myAppIdentityContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;    
})
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme)
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme)

    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ForwardAuthenticate = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<myAppUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    // Password settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;
    // Lockout settings.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    // User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
 .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
 .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<myAppUser>>()
 //.AddDefaultUI() //new commented line
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<myAppIdentityContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseMemberCasing();  
    });


//mail sender
builder.Services.Configure<SmtpSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SmtpSettings)));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MailService>();

#region API

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml"));
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = string.Format("JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter '{0}' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"{0} 1safsfsdfdfd\"", "Bearer")
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[]{}
                    }
                });
    options.SchemaFilter<SwaggerEnumHelper>(); 
    options.DocumentFilter<SwaggerDocumentFilterHelper>();
});

#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "myapplication.WebAPI v1"));
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

in fact, I commented out the line `//.AddDefaultUI()` , and it worked!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).